# What are the most important criteria to consider when purchasing a screen printing table for a home business?

Tags: screen-printing

I would like to purchase a screen printing table for my wife’s textile printing business. It would be great if the table could print textiles as large as 2’x2’.

What are the most important things I should consider?

Don’t want to go cheap and lead to headache, but also don’t want to over buy. We’re expecting the business to grow and so don’t mind purchasing a table which she can grow into.

Comment: Hi Jonathan Muse, and welcome to GD.SE. I think your question is a little out the scope of Graphic Design, maybe you can get an answer asking at https://crafts.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Printing is within the scope of the site. This question is as on-topic as any about achieving a quality image with a specific printing technology. Because most of us use ink-jet or offset doesn't make this less relevant to graphic design production, IMO.

Comment: @Danielillo. Screen printing is a subject alien to crafts and handicrafts. There are no questions or answers there related to this question. There is a reason that the screen-printing tag is here at graphic design.

Comment: The printing technologies are Intaglio, flexo, offset, digital, and **screen**.

Answer (score 1):

Alignment of the screens as the table revolves will be your biggest headache after registration of the images. The set-up must be stable.

The number of stations determines the number of colours you can get in a run. Do you want to print posterized pictures or straight one, two, three colour line graphics?

Do you have enough room for the drying racks necessary for large runs and slow drying metallic inks?

Can you buy used?

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing would be:

Size.

If you want to print 2’x2’ you need a table a bit larger than that, let's say 3’x3’. See the space needed for the mechanism that holds the frame.
Your frame probably should be around 2.5'.

Sturdiness.

---

But such a big table will not be useful for several colors. Remember that you need one octopus silk-screen printing.